# Is it safe to avoid using a "using block" with Entity Framework Core's DbContext?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, entity-framework-core, uwp-xaml

The app is simply a local UWP Windows Store app. I am using EFC with a SQLite DB. I was wondering if it makes sense to keep the context (MyContext) "alive" for the lifetime of the app. That way my docs collection will have a live representation of the actual database, and so I can add/remove/retrieve objects and bind to the docs collection.

```
ObservableCollection<Document> docs;

// Can I just skip adding the "using" block here and just keep the connection
// alive until the app is closed?
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    docs = new ObservableCollection<Document>(context.Documents);
}
```

Comment: The rule of thumb says if you create an instance of a type that implements the `IDisposable` interface, you should dispose it.

Comment: Doesn't makes sense to make it stay alive if you are not going to use it.  You may experience some memory issues (imagine if all of your applications had everything cached full-time). And as it is sqlite, I fear you may face issues with councurrency with other threads. And I agree with the rule of thumb. If it's `IDisposable`, there is a reason for it. I haven't digged into SQLite sources to check what tho

Comment: @ZoharPeled Apart from `HttpClient` ;)

Comment: @DavidG or `Tasks`... that's why it's a rule of thumb and not a definitive always.

Comment: I won't recommend doing that, it will get you into troubles over time.

Comment: When the connection time is out (default is 30 minutes), your context will become stale. So you have to catch exceptions and recreate it.